# PHP mixed with html mixed with wordpress tags gets wrong output

Tags: php, html, wordpress, syntax, lightbox

This question is really specific and for some of you guys maybe really easy to answer. I'm struggling with something for a website for a client already 2 hours.
I will try to explain it as good as possible. I made use of custom fields in Wordpress so that the customer can add images to products. I show the images in a lightbox like this (with plugin lightbox plus):    `<a rel="lightbox[<?php the_field('actietitel'); ?>]" href="<?php the_field('productafbeelding2'); ?>"> </a>` . But when there is no "productafbeelding2 for example, HTML will still creat that lightbox but it's value is NULL so it keeps loading. I'm now trying to fix it with an 'if-else-statement' which says:

```
    <?php 
     if(the_field('actie-afbeelding2') != null) 
   "<a rel='lightbox[" . the_field('actietitel');  "]' href='" . the_field('actie-afbeelding2') .  "'> </a>"
                                                           ?>
```

But for some reason it won't work (this is my hundreds attempt so sorry if it is really bad this part of code). Actually, it works but it returns the URL and not in the lightbox. But the first piece of code I showed you actually DOES return the link in a lightbox.

You can see it yourself at: http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/jorn/ambachtelijk/

Hope you guys can help me!

PS: i'm SO sorry for my grammar, I suck at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
<?php 
     if(isset(get_field('actie-afbeelding2') && get_field('actie-afbeelding2')!= "") {
   echo "<a rel='lightbox[";
   the_field('actietitel');  
   echo "]' href='";
   the_field('actie-afbeelding2');
   echo "'> </a>";
}
                                                           ?>
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your help! It doesn't work though, it still doesn't give the link in a lightbox. It returns now the field titel + the field of the URL.

Comment: What is your exact need?

Comment: What is store in`actie-afbeelding2`

Comment: There is stored an URL to a images or there is stored nothing at all, depends if the field is filed in by the customer.

Comment: Try this code `if(get_field('actie-afbeelding2') != "")`

Comment: I have this now but it return the titel + the URL of the image: `<?php
                                if (get_field('actie-afbeelding2') != "") {
                                    "<a rel='lightbox[" . the_field('actietitel');
                                    "]' href='" . the_field('actie-afbeelding2') . "'> </a>";
                                }
                                ?>` This is what should be returned in fact: `<a rel="lightbox[<?php the_field('actietitel'); ?>]" href="<?php the_field('actie-afbeelding2'); ?>"> </a>` That last line would work but is static.

Comment: Check admin side and what is the value of `'actie-afbeelding2'`

Comment: The value of 'actie-afbeelding2'  is an URL to the image or when not set it's empty.

Comment: Then try this `if(isset(get_field('actie-afbeelding2')) && get_field('actie-afbeelding2') != "")`

Comment: Hmmm, like you can see here: http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/jorn/ambachtelijk/ does it all work really good, there is just a problem with the parsing. It gives the right information but it prints the html as plain text. Instead of printing <a rel="............. etc. it just prints the fields and not in the right html tags. So the if etc all works like a charm but the parsing somehow doesn't work. I can show you in the page 'producten' what it was supposed to do ok?

Comment: To make it somewhat more clear for you, i want for every ´post´ a couple of fields to set images and when you hit the glass it shows them in a lightbox. It already works with this: `<a rel="lightbox[<?php the_field('actietitel'); ?>]" href="<?php the_field('productafbeelding5'); ?>"> </a>` the only problem is, when 'productafbeelding5' is not set, it still makes a lightbox item but it won't show (ofcourse)  and then it breaks.

Comment: Exactly! If i make it static like this: `<a rel="lightbox[<?php the_field('actietitel'); ?>]" href="<?php the_field('productafbeelding5'); ?>"> </a>` and productafbeelding5 is filed in it works like a charm. But ofcourse when productafbeelding5 for example is not filled in it breaks. So I want to make it with an if-else-statement but than it doesn't give back HTML but the fields in plain text without the <a> tag.

Comment: Ok, I have it like this now: `<?php  if(isset(get_field('actie-afbeelding2')) && get_field('actie-afbeelding2')!= "") { echo "<a rel='lightbox[";
                                  the_field('actietitel');  
                                                            echo "]' href='";
                                                            the_field('actie-afbeelding2');
                                                            echo "'> </a>";
                                                         } ?>`  But this gives on the website: http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/jorn/ambachtelijk/

Comment: try `if(get_field('actie-afbeelding2')!= "")`

Comment: Wow! It works, I deleted Isset and now it works totally fine, you dude are my hero, is there some way I can thank you?

Comment: What do you mean with "if you want any help please share to me" ? PS: accepted your answer

Comment: No. It just jocking!! have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is

```
     if(the_field('actie-afbeelding2') != null)
```

probably you should change that to != "". It's also a good idea to change the order in if condition: "" != thefield('actie-afbeelding2')

Comment: Guess that makes sense, it's still not fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use . after the_field('actietitel') instead of ;.
Moreover, you may forget to call echo.
Try this

```
if(the_field('actie-afbeelding2') != null)  {
    echo "<a rel='lightbox[" . the_field('actietitel').  "]' href='" . the_field('actie-afbeelding2') .  "'> </a>";
}
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer! It now returns the titel + the image and not in a lightbox, any idea how you can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
!empty(the_field('actie-afbeelding2'))
```

Which will, basically, test both `isset(the_field('actie-afbeelding2'))` and  `!the_field('actie-afbeelding2')` which includes `is_null(the_field('actie-afbeelding2'))`.

[this article](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)  has a good table summarizing.